# How do I change the URL of using $location with angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am currently trying to set up a table to go to a profile page when you click a row.  But $location.url will simply append the 'profile.html' to the end of the current html page and not take me to the profile page.  How do I change the current url to allow me to go to my page.

index html:

```
http://localhost:9080/AgentOnlineApp/index.html
```

html I get when I click the row:

`http://localhost:9080/AgentOnlineApp/index.html#/profile.html`

I want:

`http://localhost:9080/AgentOnlineApp/profile.html`

current AngularJS code:

```
$scope.selectTableRow = function(agent)
    {

        $location.url('/profile.html');

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the HTML5 history API, you need to set:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

If you actually want to change the location entirely and reload the page, you are not quite using Angular as intended since this wouldn't be a single page app.  However, you could do it with `window.location = "profile.html"`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this to load another page (outside your application):

`$window.location.replace("profile.html")`

Don't forget to inject `$window`